# Is it right if I say, "May I know from which countries my sales are being executed?"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

First I like to say I'm not a native speaker and sometimes I face troubles to make sentences and English learning is a continuous process.

I usually sell products and I want to know what are the people of those different countries who buy my products. So, I have a confusion with sentence making and I like to know is it grammatically correct?

If I say, **"May I know from which countries my sales are being executed?"**

Is it grammatically correct or sound appropriate? Please somebody help me out, thank you.

Comment: I can't imagine ***who*** you might pose your highlighted question to, so it's hard to say whether it's "appropriate". But consider a more "credible" (but structurally similar) question asked of a shopkeeper: *May I know from which countries your products are being imported?* It's grammatically correct, but awkward and stilted. A native speaker might instead phrase it as *Can I ask which countries you import your products from?* But "Can I ask" is a meaningless thing to include when you're asking the question anyway, so I'd just go with *Which countries do you import your products from?*

Comment: The only time it sounds idiomatic to say that a sale is *executed* is if it is the sale of something intangible, particularly a financial instrument like stock shares or shares in a mutual fund.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you. It was actually online product sales. What would you say if you were in my situation?